# Cannot connect to github server using SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I tried everything possible I could find online. So sorry if it looks like duplicated answer I looked everywhere I could and it did not help me to resolve the problem. I am trying to set SSH access for git and I created and added a key to a git.

```
dummy@dummy:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l -E md5
4096 MD5:fc:53:c6***e:e5:2b:f9 id_rsa (RSA)
dummy@dummy:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:3qSYSF7****0D3qJLO3PAII0 id_rsa (RSA)
dummy@dummy:~/.ssh$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 11388
dummy@dummy:~/.ssh$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/ilcompfad1/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So nothing works..
My permissions:

```
drwx------ 2 dummy dum 4.0K Jun 11 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 dummy dum 4.0K Jun 11 14:20 ..
-rw------- 1 dummy dum 3.2K Jun 11 13:47 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 dummy dum  744 Jun 11 13:47 id_rsa.pub
```

I did

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and everything else I could find.

I copied the key from id-rsa.pub and added to git ssh. Saved it.

What may be wrong???

Comment: Have you uploaded the public key corresponding to `mnt/dummy/user/dummy/.ssh/id_rsa` to github?

Answer (score 0):

When you visit https://github.com/settings/keys, does the key fingerprint displayed match the output of `ssh-add -l -E md5`?

Comment: Can you update the output log with a higher debug level (i.e. `-vvv`)?